# Is there a way to run other platforms (other than Atari) in an OpenAI's Gym-like environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai, gym

Is there a way to run C64, Nintendo Gameboy, or other platforms in an OpenAI's Gym-like environment? It seems that we can run only Atari games.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found

https://blog.openai.com/gym-retro/

but there may be other platforms?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/openai/retro

Current list of machines is

- Atari
- Atari2600 (via Stella)
- TurboGrafx-16/PC Engine (via Mednafen/Beetle PCE Fast)
- Game Boy/Game Boy Color (via gambatte)
- Game Boy Advance (via mGBA)
- Nintendo Entertainment System (via FCEUmm)
- Super Nintendo Entertainment System (via Snes9x)
- GameGear (via Genesis Plus GX)
- Genesis/Mega Drive (via Genesis Plus GX)
- Master System (via Genesis Plus GX)

There is a vague tutorial here for adding other systems
https://github.com/openai/retro/issues/169